# Remove object from Realm without invalidating it

Tags: swift, realm

I create few objects and show all of them in my UI. However I save only part of my objects in the Realm and at some point I'd like to remove some of the saved objects from the Realm but I want to continue using them in the UI.

However right now if I delete the objects from the realm and they are invalidated so cannot be used anymore. Is there a way to remove object from the realm without invalidating it (make the object unmanaged again) ?

Comment: In Android (Java) we can create a standalone copy of object. Like `MyEntity copy = realm.copyFromRealm(myEntity);`. Then just create a copy before remove. In Swift does not have this option?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to hide objects from the UI, but using them in the background.

1. You can add Boolean property to the `object`. If its hidden, just don't present it.
2. You can store the object elsewhere, another `realm` file, or just local array of `Objects`.

Comment: No, I do not want to hide from UI but I want to remove from the Realm without invalidating the object so I can continue use it in the UI

Answer (score 0):

It is a method called "logical delete" or "soft delete". (Antonym is "physical delete" or "hard delete") Add a property to indicate that the object was deleted. (A flag indicating that was deleted like `deleted` or assigning the deletion date like `deletionDate` or `deletedAt` are often used commonly.) Then use the property to check the property whether it has been deleted instead of physical delete.

Comment: Even if mark with flag the objects will still be part of the realm file and I want to remove them to not grow constantly. At application start I can physically delete all marked objects but this is a workaround

Comment: If you'd like to delete physically but it will be still showed on UI, the only way is split into two models. The one is Realm object, another is normal object for UI.

Comment: In that way when want to persist an object then I have to copy the object from UI model to the realm objects model and vice versa. My issue is that obviously realm objects can exist without being added to realm (i.e. to be unmanaged) but once they are added to the realm and they cannot be again made unmanaged

Comment: Yes. If you'd like to treat persisted Realm object as unmanaged, you should copy the object using `init(value:)`.